# jQuery.ajax doesn't invoke the script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My HTML file:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var session;
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.get('ajax2.php');
</script>
</body>
```

My ajax2.php file

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("final") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UPDATE `final` SET `phone_number` = `phone_number` + 1 WHERE `name` = 'gerg' ");
```

When I run ajax2.php it works just fine (increases the value by 1). However I can't access through ajax.html. Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the output of the AJAX call. You need a function to do something with the info that's returned. You probably also want some kind of button or link to trigger it as well. Otherwise you might as well load the info with the page.  Finally the mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should not use them.

Comment: Cfreak, I just need to invoke the ajax2.php, do I still need a function that would do something with the output ?

Comment: where is the server running and where is the html running? you may be running into the same origin policy issue

Comment: @fermerius Where is the accompanying `form` with the input names?

Comment: SB,both files in the same directory.

Comment: Fred, it's hardcoded for now, just to test ajax.

Comment: @fermerius Fine, but you need something to the affect of `$("#contactform").submit(function(event){` to call the function in relation to your form's name. Ajax doesn't know what to call, or where to call it from.

Comment: put a callcack as your second $.get parameter eg `$.get('ajax2.php',function(response){alert(response)});` then see what your console says

Comment: @andrew, it alerts the whole code of ajax2.php, but it doesn't run the page. is it possible to invoke script to run using jQuery.get ?

Comment: sounds like an incorrect mime type if your whole php page was returned

Comment: @andrew, how can I specify the correct type ?

Comment: if the server is your own then check the apache2 configuration, if not then google .htaccess and setting mime type for .php

Comment: thank you andrew, that was the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a slash before the name of the file:

```
$.get('/ajax2.php');
```